# how to load modified and unmodified data into materialized view in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, view, refresh, materialized-views

I have a table T_SG_LTA_TRANSACTION_TYPE in source database.
I want to move it into a target database.
I have created a materialized view log in source database.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON T_SG_LTA_TRANSACTION_TYPE WITH PRIMARY KEY, ROWID;
```

Then I created materialized view in target database with following query.

```
 CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW T_SG_LTA_TRANSACTION_TYPE
ON PREBUILT TABLE
REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND
FOR UPDATE
AS
SELECT TRANSACTION_ID,
       TRANSACTION_DESCRIPTION,
       FILE_TYPE_ID
  FROM T_SG_LTA_TRANSACTION_TYPE@EBAODWH_SRC_1_GS_AIG;
```

But when I refresh materialized view , I am unable to load the data which is already present in T_SG_LTA_TRANSACTION_TYPE(SOURCE DB).

```
BEGIN
DBMS_MVIEW.refresh('T_SG_LTA_TRANSACTION_TYPE');
END;
```

The data which is updated in source table after creation of materialized view, is only loading to materialized view . But I want to get whole data from source table(modified and unmodified) into materialized view. And I need this unmodified data only once when mview is created. Please suggest the solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using [the `ON PREBUILT TABLE` clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6002.htm#SQLRF54129) incorrectly:

> The ON PREBUILT TABLE clause lets you register an existing table as a preinitialized materialized view.

And

> Caution:
>   This clause assumes that the table object reflects the materialization of a subquery. Oracle strongly recommends that you ensure that this assumption is true in order to ensure that the materialized view correctly reflects the data in its master tables.

You're essentially saying that `T_SG_LTA_TRANSACTION_TYPE` already exists on the target database - not the source - and contains the current state of the source table; which, since you're missing data, is not true.

When you refresh Oracle is only looking for changes since the view was created, as it's supposed to; it relies on the MV log to identify what has changed.

Drop the MV in the target database, *without* the preserve table clause, and then recreate it without the `on prebuilt table` clause.

Make sure you're dropping the right thing in the right database/schema, of course...

---

It isn't clear if the (empty) table already existed in your target DB before you started; or you've run this a couple of times and dropped the MV with `preserve table` - and either the source was empty last time, or you truncated the target table afterwards - or perhaps you tried to export/import the initial state but just got the metadata and not the data. If the table you said existed on the target DB did not, in fact, exist then Oracle would have thrown an ORA-12059 exception when you tried to create the MV. I suspect you'd created an empty table and then tried to convert it to an MV, but if you do that it won't get any data from the source DB, as you've seen.